# C# - repeat for loop without using goto

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, goto

Recently, when developing a calculator program, I found myself using `goto` multiple times to restart a for loop.
Example:

```
StartLoop:

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (items[i] == condition)
    {
        //Do something
        goto StartLoop:
    }
}
```

I know that `goto` should be avoided but what other way would I have to restart the loop?

Comment: What's stopping your code from infinitely running the loop if the condition is true? Are you changing items[i] before restarting the loop?

Comment: Yes, some items charge under certain circumstances and the loop is repeated until there are no more items that need to be processed.

Comment: Also, "I know that goto should be avoided" - well, there's a reason why it's there for so many versions. Sometimes it is the best solution... Anyways, seems like a good candidate for using recursion

Comment: [`continue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/jump-statements), use sparingly but, if there is no code to jump at the end of you loop, you don't need to.

Comment: Instead of using `goto` you should try to break your program into multiple parts. Look that every part does only one thing and that you can reuse code. So provide classes and methods that you can use and call. Here you could also put the `Do something` in a method and the loop in another and the code that calls this method is in a third.

Comment: Completely agree with Tim - I was about to post an example, but the question has already been answered. I think I'll still post the example, for comparative purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the value of `i`:

```
int length = 9;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    if (i == 7)
    {
        i = -1;
    }
}
```

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
0
1
2
3
4
5
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I had tried setting i = 0 but that wasn't working (it was increased to 1 before the new iteration) so I decided to switch to using goto instead. I didn't realise I could use negative indexes.

Comment: @EliaGiaccardi - It's not an index, it's just an integer. It becomes an index only when it is used as such, i.e. `an_array[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

As per a comment from /u/Tim Schmelter, it's probably going to be clearer to split the logic into multiple methods.

If you put the loop into a bool-returning method, you can then return a value which indicates whether the loop was terminated prematurely. There's a myriad ways to do that; here's one example:

```
void processItemsUntilComplete(int[] items)
{
    static bool condition(int item) => item == 42;

    while (!processItemsUntil(items, condition))
    {
        // Keep looping until processItems() returns true to indicate that it completed.
    }
}

/// <summary>Processes items until a certain condition occurs.</summary>
/// <returns>True if all the items were processed; false if the processing was interrupted because the condition was true.</returns>
bool processItemsUntil(int[] items, Predicate<int> condition)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (condition(item))
            return false;

        // Other processing.
    }

    return true;
}
```